# Angle between vectors

Tags: vector-spaces

What is meant by angle between two vectors in dot and cross product? I.e if  $\mathbf A\cdot \mathbf B = ab\cos(p)$ than the angle p is angle from vetor **A** to **B** or what?

Comment: Geometrically, imagine you draw these vectors so that they both start at a common point, say the origin. Then you take a plane they both lie on and you have an ordinary angle, just like in a triangle on a plane.

Comment: A vector $A$ can be looked at as an arrow starting in the origin and ending at point $A$. Two such arrows make automatically an angle. If $p$ denotes this angle then $(A,B)=||A||.||B||.\cos p$.

Comment: Angle can be positive and negative but what about such circumstances?

Comment: I mean angle can be clock and anti-clockwise .

Comment: Or we are taking only its magnitude? In these cases

Comment: $cos p=\cos(-p)$ so clockwise or anti-clockwise has no influence.

Comment: What about cross product.

Comment: @Muzamil I'm pretty sure the magnitude of the cross product is defined so that $||A\times B||=||A||||B||\; |\sin{p}|$ in which case $|\sin(-p)|=|\sin(p)|$.

Comment: So u mean p is from A to B vector?

Comment: And only positive sin(p) is considered.?

Comment: No I mean it makes no difference as drhab stated. If you measured clockwise then the angle would be $p$, but anti-clockwise it would be $-p$. Both the equations for the dot product and mag. of the cross product are no different whether you put in $p$ or $-p$. If you take the cross product to be $A\times B=||A||||B|| \sin{p}\; \hat{n}$ ($\hat{n}$ is unit vector perp. to both $A$ & $B$) then it's clear that $||A\times B||=||A||||B|| |\sin{p}|\; ||\hat{n}||$ where by definition $||\hat{n}||=1$. So it comes naturally that it doesn't matter whether you consider the clockwise or anticlockwise angle.

Comment: Though the angle does make a difference when just considering the cross product of $A$ and $B$ (not the magnitude). But it only makes a difference in sign: $A\times B=-B\times A$. Since the cross product produces a vector, the difference is in which direction this vector points, that is, whether it 'pointing up' from the plane containing $A$ and $B$ or 'pointing down'. Though it's a bit vague to talk about it like that.